# How to setup nginx for roundcube in ispconfig server?

Tags: linux, nginx, roundcube

Hello im working on school project, I installed ISPConfig which configured nginx server and it works, now I want to enable roundcube webmail.
Im running ubuntu so I used apt-get

```
apt-get install roundcube roundcube-plugins roundcube-plugins-extra
```

The wizard configured my MySQL database for roundcube
and install roundcube web files to /usr/share/roundcube and in /var/lib/roundcube I have links to /usr/share/roundcube.

Now I need to tell nginx if someone request URL myispconfig.tld/webmail it open roundcube.
But I'm not sure how to do this, maybe some alias or creating vhost ? I can configure apache but I'm new in nginx. I read roundcube documentation so next configuration I think I can handle. Thank you

edit: i tried add to /etc/nginx/sites-available/ispconfig.vhost

```
location  /webmail/ {
  alias  /usr/share/roundcube/;
}
```

but after nginx reload no changes :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOLVED: same configuration for squirrelmail works :-)

```
  location /roundcube {
          root /usr/share/;
           index index.php index.html index.htm;
           location ~ ^/roundcube/(.+\.php)$ {
                   try_files $uri =404;
                   root /usr/share/;
                   fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
                   fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
                   fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
                   fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;

                   fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $request_filename;
                   fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
                   fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
                   fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI            $document_uri;
                   fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
                   fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;

                   fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE       CGI/1.1;
                   fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE         nginx/$nginx_version;

                   fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
                   fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
                   fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR             $server_addr;
                   fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
                   fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME             $server_name;

                   fastcgi_param   HTTPS                   $https;

                   # PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
                   fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS         200;
                   # To access SquirrelMail, the default user (like www-data on Debian/Ubuntu) mu$
                   #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                   fastcgi_index index.php;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                   fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
                   fastcgi_buffers 256 4k;
                   fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
                   fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
           }
           location ~* ^/roundcube/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                   root /usr/share/;
           }
           location ~* /.svn/ {
                   deny all;
           }
           location ~* /README|INSTALL|LICENSE|SQL|bin|CHANGELOG$ {
                   deny all;
           }

    }
```

Note: Debian users should change "root /usr/share/;" with "root /var/lib/;" throughout the configuration file (there are three places). Else they will get an 404 error as whatermark.

Comment: I would like to note that it is better to adjust `/user/local/ispconfig/server/conf/nginx_apps.vhost.master` or make a custom config in `/usr/local/ispconfig/server/conf-custom/`. Otherwise your configuration will be overwritten.